# Upload a image on server iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I am new to iPhone. I want to upload an image to a server. I have url

**http://lifestander.com:8080/fileupload/uploadfile.html?username=tom&password=1234&directory=ebay&filename=fantacy.jpg**

I use the following method for uploading the file, but the result in console is: **{"success":"false", "message":"Authentication Failed"}**

I do not understand the output in the console. So please tell me what do I do wrong, or improve my code. What to do?

Thanks.

```
-(void)uploadFile{

UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"jpg"];



NSString *photoUploadURLString=@"http://lifestander.com:8080/fileupload/uploadfile.html";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: photoUploadURLString];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];



// Upload an image
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage,1.0);

[request addPostValue:@"tom" forKey:@"username"];
[request addPostValue:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];
[request addPostValue:@"ebay" forKey:@"directory"];



[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"images.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:@"filename"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

[request startAsynchronous];



}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it's a code fault, since there is no crash and you receive a response. `{"success":"false", "message":"Authentication Failed"}` means that there is something wrong with the [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication). Check if there is any login/password/acces key required to upload your file and if yes, implement it.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. i wants ask i am doing the right way?

Comment: Your code is correct, I am using ASIFormDataRequest in a similar way. The error must be here: `[request addPostValue:@"tom" forKey:@"username"]; [request addPostValue:@"1234" forKey:@"password"];`. Are you sure this is correct login data?

Comment: yes. username and password  are correct. please look on my url which i used in NSString *photoUploadURLString. it is correct or I use full url ?